# Suppressing SyntaxWarning in Python prior to compiling

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Python 2.7, and have been experimenting with Python's Tkinter module. I tried building a calculator that would accept two inputs and feed them into functions of my own devising. I then tried to define a function that would let me replace either one of the inputs globally, so that it would be accepted by every other function (instead of limiting myself to just two inputs everytime I run the program).

This solution works perfectly; unfortunately, it also raises a SyntaxWarning in my command window prior to the code being executed, which I don't want to have to see. I've exhausted the documentation on suppressing warnings, and sadly warnings.filterwarnings() isn't coming to my rescue. I've been led to assume the problem lies with the compilation, rather than the execution.

I'd appreciate any advice or help in this regard, or if someone could show me how to modify my syntax to accomplish the same effect.

I'm using Button widgets that only seem to work the way I want them to when I employ a function in their command parameter, so unless someone can tell me how to get beyond using just functions in there, I can't quite figure out how to modify my syntax.

Here's the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

n1 = int(raw_input("N1?"))
n2 = int(raw_input("N2?"))

def add():
    print n1+n2
def multiply():
    print n1*n2
def power():
    print pow(n1,n2)
def replacen1():
    N1 = int(raw_input("Enter n1 replacement here"))
    n1 = N1
    global n1
def replacen2():
    N2 = int(raw_input("Enter n2 replacement here"))
    n2 = N2
    global n2

Button(text = "Add",command = add).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(text = "Multiply", command = multiply).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(text = "Power", command = power).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(text = "Replace N1?", command = replacen1).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(text = "Replace N2?", command = replacen2).pack(side=LEFT)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't suppress the warnings unless they're truly out of your control. Read what they say:

```
SyntaxWarning: name 'n1' is assigned to before global declaration
```

The warning says that you're assigning to `n1` before you declare it as a global with `global n1`. So to fix your code, move the `global n1` line to the top of your function (or anywhere above the spot where you assign to `n1`):

```
def replacen1():
    global n1

    N1 = int(raw_input("Enter n1 replacement here"))
    n1 = N1
```

Do the same thing for `n2`.